# Call a function on click on a transcluded element inside an AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a modal directive because I want to have a couple of modal on a page. I used this tutorial to achieve this : http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/

To begin, here is my directive code, which is pretty the same as the one in the previous tutorial :

```
//here, app is an AngularJS module
app.directive('modal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.hide = function() {
                scope.show = false;
                document.body.classList.remove('wwf-noScroll');
            };
        },
        template: '<div class="Modal" ng-show="show"><div class="Modal-overlay" ng-click="hide()"></div><button class="Modal-close" ng-click="hide()"></button><div class="Modal-content" ng-transclude></div></div>'
    };
});
```

Then here is how I use it :

```
<modal show="showInformationsModal">
    <h2 class="Modal-title">Informations</h2>
    <button type="button">Close this</button>
</modal>
```

What I want to achieve is being able to close the modal (ie. call the `hide` function defined in the directive's scope). But I can't put the button in the template of my directive because sometimes I want a button in the modal to close it, but sometimes not, and the text inside this button will never be the same.

I tried some things like :

- `<button type="button" ng-click="hide()">Close this</button>`
- `<button type="button" ng-click="showInformationsModal = false">Close this</button>`
- `<button type="button" ng-click="show = false">Close this</button>`

Nothing worked. I think I'm missing something ! Can somebody help me ?

Thank you,

Cyrille

Comment: You could still put the button in your modal's template and just hide it when you don't want it to be closed that way, as well as dynamically generate text, either via an attribute, or some logic in your modal's controller. Would that not work?

Comment: Can you the modal code in a jsfiddle. We'll be able to help in a much better way...

Comment: Here is a CodePen with the code : http://codepen.io/JesmoDrazik/pen/NqZLYR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

As it was pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143161/call-a-function-on-click-on-a-transcluded-element-inside-an-angularjs-directive/32154686?noredirect=1#comment65131867_32154686), the `transclude` function can be more generic by replacing `var contentElement = element[0].querySelector('.Modal-content');` with `var contentElement = element[0].querySelector('[ng-transclude]');`

**ORIGINAL**

A friend sent me this link : http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

What I was missing is precisely what this link is pointing out : transcluded HTML's scope is not directive's isolated scope.

I used the fifth parameter of the `link` function :

```
transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
  var contentElement = element[0].querySelector('.Modal-content');
  contentElement.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < clone.length; ++i) {
    contentElement.appendChild(clone[i]);
  }
});
```

Here is the codepen updated. I don't know if it's the most beautiful way to solve my problem, but it solves it ! http://codepen.io/JesmoDrazik/pen/NqZLYR?editors=001

Comment: This works. Angular really sucks for this sort of weirdness. You can make the function a little more generic with var contentElement = element[0].querySelector('[ng-transclude]');